# Directed graph and complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

I have a problem finding the complexity in my program. 
It consists of one directed graph where each node has an arraylist of edges.

Do anyone know the complexsity of searching trough this directed graph?

My code:

```
class Project{
    ArrayList<Task> subProject = null;
    int manpower, maxNr;



    Project(int maxNr, int manpower){
          this.maxNr = maxNr;
          this.manpower = manpower;
          subProject = new ArrayList<Task>();
     }
}

class Task {
    int id, time, staff, slack;
    String name;
    int earliestStart, latestStart, finished;
    ArrayList<Edge> outEdges = null;
    int cntPredecessors;
    Boolean rund;

    Task(int n){
        id = n;
        cntPredecessors = 0;
        outEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        rund = false;
    }
}

class Edge {
    int edges;

    Edge(int edges){
        this.edges = edges;
    }
}

public void run(){
        while(runTasks == false){
            System.out.println("Time: " + runT);
            for(Task t: subProject){
                if(t.cntPredecessors == 0 && t.rund == false){ // Checks if there is no edges to the task and if the task hasen't started
                    System.out.println("        Starting: " + t.id);
                    ferdige.add(t);
                    t.rund = true;
                    t.earliestStart = runT;
                    t.finished = runT + t.time;
                    if(cirdep < t.finished){
                        cirdep = t.finished;
                    }
                    tId = t.id;
                    workers += t.staff;
                    System.out.println("        Current staff: " + workers);
                }
                if(t.cntPredecessors == 0 && t.finished == runT){
                    maxNr--;
                    System.out.println("        Finished: " + t.id);
                    minPre(t.id);
                    workers -= t.staff;
                }
                if((t.cntPredecessors == 0 && t.rund == false) || (t.cntPredecessors == 0 && t.finished == runT)){
                    System.out.println("        Current staff: " + workers);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to answer some questions.  Is the graph acyclic?  Is it connected? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

With mo more information to go on, you can at least say it's $O(|V|)$ by using depth first search.  But you have to do something to take care of isolated components, 'cause DFS can't get to a node if there's no path.